# Как передать NULL в перегруженную функцию? PLS-00307: Слишком много описаний 'MY_FUNC' соответствующих этому вызову

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

У меня есть несколько перегруженных функций в пакете. Например:

```
function my_func(i_val varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
  return '!' || i_val || '!';
end;

function my_func(i_val number) return varchar2 is
begin
  return to_char(i_val+1);
end;
```

И всё замечательно до тех пор, пока мы передаем значения, отличные от `NULL`. И даже `NULL` мы можем передать, если заранее присвоим его в переменную. То есть рабочим будет код:

```
declare
  a number;
  b varchar2(32767);
begin
  b := my_pkg.my_func(i_val => a);
end;
```

Но если мы передадим скаляр, равный NULL:

```
declare
  b varchar2(32767);
begin
  b := my_pkg.my_func(i_val => null);
end;
```

То поймаем ошибку:

> PLS-00307: Слишком много описаний 'MY_FUNC' соответствующих этому вызову

Можно ли как-то исключить эту ситуацию? Например, явно задав, какую функцию вызывать в таком случае.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У литерала `NULL` нет конкретного типа данных, это «ничто».

В PL/SQL, в отличии от SQL, литерал `NULL` не приводится по умолчанию к `VARCHAR2`, поэтому надо подсказать компилятору, какой тип данных подразумевается.

Например явно (рекомендуемо):

```
var ret varchar2 (8)
exec :ret := pack.func (cast (null as varchar2))

RET
---
!!
```

Или более короткими подсказками:

```
exec :ret := pack.func (''||null)

RET
---
!!

exec :ret := pack.func (0+null)

RET
----
null
```

Comment: В общем-то, фокус с переменной равной null был примерно в том же самом. Была гепотеза, что можно при создании функций выдать одной из них приоритет каким-нибудь служебным словом в заголовке. Понятно, что пальцем в небо :) Но и вопрос был скорее из любопытства для себя. "Не прокатило - вычеркиваем" (с) Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: У вас что ни вопрос - надежда на чудо )) "Чудес не бывает" (ц).